# How to merge nested objects with the same key

Tags: javascript, object

I'm having a hard time merging nested objects with potentially the same key using `Object.assign()`;

See code as an example

```
// Initial structure
let state = {
    pageIndex: 1,
    allResults: {
        queries: {}
    }
}
```

Code

```
const assign = (query, page) => {
    const obj = {
        [page]: {
            res: 'hi'
        }
    }

    state.allResults.queries = Object.assign(
        {},
        state.allResults.queries,
        state.allResults.queries[query] || {[query]: {}},
        obj
    )
}

assign('hi', state.pageIndex);
assign('hi', (state.pageIndex + 1));
assign('hello', (state.pageIndex + 1));

console.log(state)
```

What I'm getting

```
state = {
    pageindex: 1,
    allResults: {
        queries: {
            1: {
                res: 'hi'
            },
            2: {
                res: 'hi'
            },
            hello: {},
            hi: {}
        }
    }
}
```

What I expect

```
let state = {
    pageIndex: 1,
    allResults: {
        queries: {
            hi: {
                1: {
                    res: 'h'
                },
                2: {
                    res: 'h'
                }
            },
            hello: {
                2: {
                    res: 'h'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, this the way how I'm doing it doesn't really work, and I can't figure out how to get the expected result.

Thanks in advance

Comment: And you want us to guess what your expected result is, right?

Comment: Edit your question to show what you expect, and what you are actually getting.

Comment: @connexo I added the expected result as in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could work for you:

```
const assign = (query, page) => {
    const obj = {
        [page]: {
            res: 'hi'
        }
    }

    let _obj = Object.assign(
        {},
        state.allResults.queries[query] || {},
        obj
    );

    state.allResults.queries = Object.assign(
        {},
        state.allResults.queries,
        { [query]: _obj }
    )
}
```

First I created the plain object that will be assigned to the subQuery object. Then I merge it into a existing (if not, `{}` an empty) object.

After that I just merge that into the query object.

Hope that it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

This will assign the desired sub key of the `queries` key which you send to the `assign` function (`hi` or `hello`) to their previous value, combined with the new value.

```
state.allResults.queries[query] = Object.assign(
    {},
    state.allResults.queries[query] || {},
    obj
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a nested `Object.assign`.

```js
const assign = (query, page) => {
    const obj = { [page]: { res: 'hi' } }
    state.allResults.queries = Object.assign(
        {},
        state.allResults.queries,
        { [query]: Object.assign(state.allResults.queries[query] || {}, obj) }
    );
}

let state = { pageIndex: 1, allResults: { queries: {} } };

assign('hi', state.pageIndex);
assign('hi', (state.pageIndex + 1));
assign('hello', (state.pageIndex + 1));

console.log(state)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```